# How to unselect selected text in jupyter or how to make click & drag always select?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I select a code in a Jupyter notebook cell, the code stays selected as long as I don't click into a different part of the same cell that is not selected. So, for example, if I select more text than I wanted, I have to click outside of the selection first, before being able to re-select the portion you want. This is very annoying, particularly if I select all the text within a cell and then want to select a smaller portion of text. I need to scroll up or down to the edge of the selection and click exactly before or after the selected text to unselect it again. Is there a way to make the jupyter notebook behave in a way that every click and drag creates a new selection rather than moving already selected text?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want a way to reduce the size of the selected text area. You can do this holding shift-clicking within the selected text box, this will move the end-marker to the point where you clicked.

Unfortunately this only works with the end-marker and not the start-marker as is standard. [I have raised a ticket with codemirror (the project that jupyter-notebook uses for the text editor).](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/4394)